# Get some columns from table A and some from table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns i need to show all the records in column [PR] and some columns from column [EM]. The below SQL statement does not return all the records from column [PR].

```
SELECT 
    [PR].[WBS1], [EM].[FirstName], [EM].[LastName], [EM].[EMail]
FROM 
    [VisionDemo].[dbo].[PR] 
JOIN 
    [VisionDemo].[dbo].[EM] ON [VisionDemo].[dbo].[PR].[Principal] = [VisionDemo].[dbo].[EM].[Employee]
```

How do I do this ?

Comment: You have no `column A` in your query.  Your question doesn't actually make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT [PR].[WBS1],[EM].[FirstName],[EM].[LastName], [EM].[EMail]
FROM [VisionDemo].[dbo].[PR] 
LEFT JOIN [VisionDemo].[dbo].[EM] 
ON [VisionDemo].[dbo].[PR].[Principal] = [VisionDemo].[dbo].[EM].[Employee]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. This is fundamental stuff, go check out the FAQ

```
SELECT [PR].[WBS1],[EM].[FirstName],[EM].[LastName], [EM].[EMail]
FROM [VisionDemo].[dbo].[PR] 
LEFT JOIN [VisionDemo].[dbo].[EM] --Use a left join
ON [VisionDemo].[dbo].[PR].[Principal] = [VisionDemo].[dbo].[EM].[Employee]
```